# How do I make a list of all links on a web page (DownThemAll!)?

Tags: internet, download-manager

How can I download the links (not the content in the pages that the links point to, just the links themselves.  I'm trying to give a list of about 300 videos to my network admin to unblock, he just wants the URLs.

Comment: If you were coding this, you could just use regex to pull out the link tags...

Comment: I'll do that, thanks.  Add it as an answer to recieve credit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP:

```
<?php

$webpagehtml=file_get_contents("http://www.example.com");

$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($webpagehtml);

$xpath=new DOMXPath($dom);
$items = $xpath->query("//a");

$links=array();

for ($i = 0;  $i < $items->length; $i++ ) {
$item = $items->item($i);
$title=$item->textContent;
$href=$item->getAttribute('href');

if($href && $title){
echo "$href = $title<br/>";
}
}
?>
```

In Python, use http://arshaw.com/scrapemark/docs/examples/.

Or you can use [downthemall](http://downthemall.net/) in firefox to do the dirty work.

Answer (score 2):

When I want to see the links on a webpage, I grab an old copy of Avant browser (ver 10) out of my archives and install it. Run the webpage you want. Right-click on the page and select "Open All Links in This page." You can't cut-and-paste them.